# How to read the IISExpressSSLPort dynamically in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reflection, iis-express

Quick question, hopefully a simply answer. When working with a Web Project in Visual Studios, if I enable SSL, it generates an SSL URL.

The problem I'm having is that when I run the application (debugging), it wants to start using http on whatever port that is. So my fix is to basically ..

```
if (HttpContext.Request.IsLocal == true)
{
   myUriBuilder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
   myUriBuilder.Port = 44331;
}
```

I would very much like to be able to dynamically determine what that SSL port is for this project without having to hard code it (code re-usability)

I know that port is located in the .csproj file under the node IISExpressSSLPort, but short of trying to parse up the file, I thought I'd reach out and see if someone knows a way to grab that value in code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

So without a clean way to really do it, I ended up just using my home-grown xml reader to pull that info. You would have to implement your own xml reader (the middle line), but basically you read the file just from the root (when in debug mode)

```
var myXMLTools = new File.XMLTools(Server.MapPath("~/$safeprojectname$.csproj"));
```

This would be where you use an XML reader to pull the "/PropertyGroup/IISExpressSSLPort" node and grab it's value...

```
string myDevPort = myXMLTools.GetXMLEntry("/").GetChildEntries("PropertyGroup").First().GetProperty(File.XMLTools.PropertyTypes.Element, "IISExpressSSLPort", false).Text;
```

And now you have the port

```
myUriBuilder.Port = Convert.ToInt32(myDevPort);
```